# Backup Zookeeper data on active server

Tags: apache-zookeeper, database-backups, snapshot, transaction-log

I am trying to configure production-ready Zookeeper data backup.

As I learned from different sources, Zookeeper snapshot file is not enough to guarantee a return to a previous state. In fact, **the snapshot file may not even represent the state of the tree at any point in time** (see [corresponding stackoverflow ticket answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152127/is-a-zookeeper-snapshot-file-enough-to-restore-state#answer-28153048)).

So to make the consistent zk data storage backup (to store it on a cloud or elsewhere), I need to copy snapshots **with** transaction logs.
The question is: how can I copy transaction log files while zookeeper is active and makes hundreds of transactions a second? Won't the files be corrupted?

What other practices can be used in this case?